# git: Setting anyone's email address in .gitconfig

Tags: git, security

I was playing around with git when I realized that it's possible for me to commit something to a repository as another user (explained a scenario below for better understanding) and it is not considered a security vulnerability, understandably so (see [this](https://bounty.github.com/ineligible.html#impersonating_a_user_through_git_email_address)).

For example, let's assume I have push access to some repository called AAA, and my email address is `abc@xyz.com`. I can simply edit `~/.gitconfig` on my system and set the email address as some other person's email address: `def@pqr.com`. Then, I make some changes in my local repository and commit them (remember, with the email address `def@pqr.com`; git tracks commits by email address). Now, if I try to push to the remote repository, it asks for the username and password. I put mine and since I have push access to AAA, it goes through. I've successfully pushed commits on behalf of the owner of `def@pqr.com`.

So basically, in this way, I can impersonate people and add commits on their behalf. BUT AGAIN, this is not considered a vulnerability (link for reason attached before).

**Question**
It would be much easier if git didn't allow changing the email address so easily. Why hasn't git implemented OAuth, or something of that sort, for every time that the email address is changed in `~/.gitconfig`, yet?

Comment: That's why in _important_ projects you sign stuff, otherwise people could do this just like that.

Comment: About your question: what? I think you need to wrap around the concept of working distributed. You want to authenticate against _your own repo_??? you _own it_. Why would you want to check that you are indeed you?

Comment: @eftshift0, what I mean to say is that I could add your email address to my ~/.gitconfig file by simply modifying it, and then proceed to add commits on your behalf. (And then push to the remote repository, where it'll show that you've committed.) Why is it so easy for me to impersonate someone and add commits on their behalf in the first place?

Comment: Ok... let me take up your example. Can you _push_ into one of the repos that I own? If you _could_, then we would be talking about a security problem.

Comment: No. But I can add commits as you and push to a repo that I own or have push access to.

Comment: Alright, how about this: consider a situation where we're both in the same team and have access to a repo. I can make some messed up changes to the code, commit those messed up changes on your behalf, and push to the repo. So now you'll be held accountable for those changes.

Comment: Sure.... just like I could create an account in basically any site and say that I am you and start posting stuff. Does that mean that internet is insecure? Well.... _it is_ insecure, but not because of this.

Comment: Hm, that does make sense. 
But in this case, I'm not creating an account in your name. I'm able to make changes in your name, using an already existing account in your name, created by you, with which you've (possibly) been associated for a long time.

Comment: Come on! Now you are starting to sound like a crook. I mean, for real... if you committed/pushed something on _my_ behalf and you are affecting _my_ reputation in the company, this could end up in police calls / law suits if needed.... and there's probably tracing that can be followed to see what _really_ happened.

Comment: Sure, it would be surprising if there wasn't. But the fact that I'm allowed to set anyone's email in my ~/.gitconfig is what brings me to my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [explained on the list](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20200611225216.GZ6569@camp.crustytoothpaste.net/T/), this is because many projects, such as Linux and Git, work on a patch basis with a maintainer who integrates patches from a variety of people.  Therefore, being able to push data for any author is important.  If you spoofed someone else's email address on a patch, they would be informed of that by receiving review comments that they had not solicited.

Some projects also do not care very much about who wrote the patch, but instead about whether the patch is of good quality.  The author and committer information is for attribution, not identity checking, and so the author is ultimately irrelevant to the project.

If you're concerned about spoofing of identities, it's super easy to require commit signing.  GitHub offers this as an option for repositories that you can use.  However, it imposes some burden on other people to contribute, since it requires people to get GnuPG set up appropriately.

If you're operating on a platform such as GitHub, you can also just refuse to accept pull requests if the user ID associated with the PR is not the same one as associated with the commits, which is a valid approach; this can even be done via CI if you like.